# How to set a CI-Variable for a Merge-Request Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I usually set ci-variables when pushing to Gitlab with

```
git push -o ci.variable="GROUPS=1,2,3"
```

Unfortunately this is only affective for normal pipelines and not for Merge-Request pipelines. I am also unable to set a ci-variable via the Webinterface of Gitlab.

Is there any chance to set a ci-variable for a Merge-Request pipeline?

Comment: If you go to the MR in the web UI, then click the "pipelines" tab, there should be a run pipeline button that lets you set variables, I believe. I don't think there's a way to do it with push options specifically.

Comment: That was also my expectation but the "Run Pipeline" button within the "Pipelines" tab of the Merge-Request will immediately start the pipeline without showing the "set variables page" before.

For usual pipelines it is possible to set the variables using the command above. Just for Merge-Request pipelines it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rules:if` when source equal merge_request_event and  `rules:variables` like this:

```yaml
job-name:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      variables:
        VARIABLE_NAME: 'is merge request'
  script:
    - echo "do something"
```

Comment: No. I want the variable to be dynamically changed on the push event

Comment: @Toroid How do you want to decide your variable? From the previous job or decided by job script?

Comment: I want the variable to be manually specified by the user that us performing the push. As given by the command `git push -o ci.variable="GROUPS=1,2,3"`

Comment: push option `ci.variable` does not support merge request pipelines

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd